expo-auth-session response type "dismiss"
I am trying to use the Instagram basic display api to display a users Instagram pictures in my react-native expo app. After authentication via Instagram, the user is redirected to the redirectUri. As the facebook developers platform did not accept the expo redirect uri as a valid url, I created my own endpoint that converts the https url to a uri of the form exp://10.5...
This works perfectly.
However, the response type is always "dismiss".
Here is the code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import * as AuthSession from "expo-auth-session";
import {
  getInstagramPhotos,
  getAccessToken,
  exchangeCodeForToken,
} from "@/services/instagram";
import { ThemedText } from "../themedComponents/ThemedText";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";

// Replace with your actual client ID
const CLIENT_ID =
  process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID ||
  "YOUR_EXPO_PUBLIC_INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID";

const REDIRECT_URI = "https://custom-endpoint/192.168.86.114:8081";

const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
  tokenEndpoint: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
};

const InstagramIntegration = () => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
      usePKCE: false,
      scopes: ["user_profile", "user_media"],
      responseType: "code",
    },
    discovery
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AuthSession response:", response);
    router.push("/profile");

    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { code } = response.params;
      exchangeCodeForToken(code)
        .then(() => {
          setIsAuthenticated(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else if (response?.type === "error") {
      console.log("FAILED");
    }
  }, [response]);

  const checkAuthentication = async () => {
    const token = await getAccessToken();
    setIsAuthenticated(!!token);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthentication();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const fetchPhotos = async () => {
        try {
          const fetchedPhotos = await getInstagramPhotos();
          console.log(fetchedPhotos); // Log URLs
          setPhotos(fetchedPhotos);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };

      fetchPhotos();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  const handleInstagramLogin = async () => {
    console.log("LOGGING IN");
    promptAsync({ showInRecents: true });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!isAuthenticated ? (
        <View
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            borderColor: "white",
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 20,
            marginVertical: 20,
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleInstagramLogin}>
            <ThemedText>Connect to Instagram</ThemedText>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <ThemedText style={styles.instagramHeader}>
              Instagram Photos
            </ThemedText>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.instagramGrid}>
            {photos.map((photo, index) => (
              <Image
                key={index}
                source={{ uri: photo }}
                style={styles.instagramPhoto}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  headerContainer: {
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  instagramHeader: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  instagramGrid: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  instagramPhoto: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  errorText: {
    color: "red",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

export default InstagramIntegration;


The custom endpoint receives the code token, as I can see in the logs.
What might be the cause of the dismissed response?
